# C++ function in switch statement is not executing

Tags: c++, function, switch-statement

I'm new to c++ and I'm trying to make a simple class roster program that accepts new students storing the student data in an array that then be sorted and display the contents of the array.  However when running the program and entering the menu selection, two of the three functions do not work.  Any help or guidance is much appreciated. My code is here.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

//Create Students class
class Students
{
public:
    char sFirstName[256];
    char sLastName[256];
    int sStudentID; 
    double sGrade; 
    double sGPA; 
    double nCreditHours; 
};

//functions 
Students addStudent();
//void displayRoster();
//void sortRoster(); 
void showMenu();
void showWelcome(); 

//Welcome function 
void showWelcome()
{
    cout << "Welcome to my class roster program. \n"
        << "This program can be used to add students to the roster, \n"
        << "which can then be sorted by either name or I.D. number. \n" 
        << endl; 
}

//Menu function 
void showMenu()
{
    cout << "        Student Roster: \n"
        << "MAIN MENU PLEASE SELECT AN OPTION" << endl;
    cout << "1)  Add student to roster: " << endl; 
    cout << "2)  Display current roster: " << endl;
    cout << "3)  Sort roster: " << endl; 
    cout << "4)  Exit program: "  << endl; 
    //cout << "5)  Display roster sorted by 'student I.D.': " << endl; 
    //cout << "6)  Display roster sorted by 'Grade': " << endl; 
    //cout << "7)  Display roster sorted by 'GPA': \n" << endl;
    cout << "        Make your selection:  \n" << endl;
}

//Add student function 
Students addStudent()
{
    Students student; 

    cout << "Add student to roster. \n" 
        << "Enter first name: " << endl; 
    cin >> student.sFirstName; 
    cout << "Enter last name: " << endl; 
    cin >> student.sLastName; 
    cout << "Enter student I.D.: " << endl; 
    cin >> student.sStudentID; 

    return student;  
}

void displayStudent(Students student)
{
    cout << "Student name: " << student.sFirstName << " "
        << student.sLastName << endl; 
    cout << "I.D. # " << student.sStudentID << endl; 
}

void displayRoster()
{
    Students student[256];
    int nCount;

    for (int index = 0; index < nCount; index++)
    {
        displayStudent(student[index]); 
    }
}

int getStudents(Students student[], int nMaxSize)
{
    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < nMaxSize; index++)
    {
        char uInput;
        cout << "Enter another student to the roster? (Y/N): ";
        cin >> uInput;
        if (uInput != 'y' && uInput != 'Y')
        {
            break;
        }

        student[index] = addStudent();
    }

    return index; 
}

void sortRoster()
{
    Students student[256];
    int nCount;

    //bubble swap 
    int nSwaps = 1; 
    while (nSwaps != 0)
    {
        nSwaps = 0; 

        for (int n = 0; n < (nCount - 1); n++)
        {
            if (student[n].sStudentID > student[n+1].sStudentID)
            {
                Students temp = student[n+1];
                student[n+1] = student[n]; 
                student[n] = temp; 

                nSwaps++; 
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() 
{
    int selection;  //menu selection variable 

    //constants for menu selection 
    const int ADD_STUDENT = 1, 
        DISPLAY_ROSTER = 2, 
        SORT_ROSTER = 3,
        QUIT_PROGRAM = 4;

    Students student[256];
    //int nCount = getStudents(student, 256);

    do 
    {
        showWelcome(); //Show welcome message
        showMenu(); //Show menu options 
        cin >> selection; 

        while (selection < ADD_STUDENT || selection > QUIT_PROGRAM)
        {
            cout << "Enter a valid selection: "; 
            cin >> selection; 
        }

        if (selection != QUIT_PROGRAM)
        {
            switch (selection)
            {
            case ADD_STUDENT:
                addStudent();
                break; 
            case DISPLAY_ROSTER:
                displayRoster();
                break; 
            case SORT_ROSTER:
                sortRoster();
                break; 
            }
        }
    }

    while (selection != QUIT_PROGRAM);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? Does it enter `case` statement? Does it enter function? What happens? Exception or no `case` found?

Comment: *"two of the three functions do not work"* - it's expected that people post minimal code with specific problems, including what input they used, what they observed happening, how that differs from what they expect/want to happen, and what they don't understand about the difference. I suggest you spend time adding trace statements ala `std::cout << "x is now " << x << '\n';` to your code until you understand the problem yourself. If you genuinely get stuck on something specific, ask again.

Answer (score 1):

Your `nCount` is not initialised. Since this variable is used in those two functions (and assuming that it refers to the total count), you can declare it as a global variable:

```
nCount=0;
```

Everytime you add a new entry, you can increment the counter as:

```
nCount++;
```

Another suggestion to make your code actually work:

```
                 student[i++]=addStudent();
```

where `i` is a counter initialised to `0`. Your `addStudent()` function returns an object, and you discard it. Store it in the array of objects you created:

```
          Students student[256];
```

Also, since you use the above in almost all functions, it is best to declare it as global rather than redeclaring in each function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the `switch`.

The `addStudent()` is not adding the student into any list or array. Also since it return type is `Students` you should add it into the any array of `Students`. Since you have not stored any data display won't display anything.

The another problem is of `nCount`. You are using it in for comparison without initializing it. Also to keep `nCount` synchronized either make it global, use as pointer or handle it with return.

Also the problem is in `displayRoster()`. You are declaring `Students` array as `Students student[256];` and you are using it without initializing. Also if initialized, it won't have the data which was given as input.

NOTE: Sit and read your code again, there are many more mistakes. Try visualizing how your data should be stored and how your code is to behave and then start writing code.